# How can I make a python StreamWriter REQUIRE unicode input?

Tags: python, unicode, codec

The python codecs module provides StreamWriter classes for transparently encoding output streams.  For instance:

```
outstream = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.__stdout__)
outstream.write(u'\u2713')
outstream.write(' A-OK!\n') # I want this to fail!
outstream.close()
```

However the problem I have with the default StreamWriter is that it will except str objects as well as unicode objects.  If my program is writing a str to this stream, it is a bug and I want it to fail! Is there a way to make this happen without writing my own StreamWriter that enforces the type of objects written?

Also, I don't want my solution to be sensitive to  `sys.stdout.encoding`, `sys.stdout.isatty()`, `locale.getpreferredencoding()`, `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`, `os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"]` or whatever other ways python has of trying to be clever.

Comment: why can't you just do an isinstance check on the output strings? or, better still, simply avoid mixing bytes and unicode objects within your program.

Comment: I don't want to manually add an isinstance check every time I write to the stream.  It would be great if I could "simply avoid" mixing bytes and unicode objects, but the fact is with python 2 this is hard.  A lot of libraries, both in the standard lib and third-party, will take the unicode you give them but pass back a str. The goal here is to fail fast, figure out who is the bad actor, and then convert their returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, do what you're trying to do in Python 3, which has a much stronger distinction between unicode and bytes. Failing that, you'll need to subclass `StreamWriter`, for example:

```
import codecs

class StrictUTF8Writer(codecs.StreamWriter):
    '''A StreamWriter for utf8 that requires written objects be unicode'''
    encode = codecs.utf_8_encode

    def write(self, object):
        if not isinstance(object, unicode):
            raise ValueError('write() requires unicode object')
        return codecs.StreamWriter.write(self, object)
```

Comment: Advicing to use Python 3, but solution given can't work in Python 3 since StreamWritter is an empty interface and stdout doesn't accept bytes as input anymore.

Comment: Yes. I offered two solutions: use Python 3, or 'failing that' subclass StreamWriter. The second solution is only needed if you can't use Python 3.